# difference between two words for balance of account

Tags: translation, word-choice

I want to pay off the remainder of my credit card bill.

Can someone help me differentiate between 余额 and 尾数?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

余额 means credit balance, the amount of money remaining in your credit card account.

For 尾数, it usually means when you buy something which is not available yet, the shop may require you to pay some money first (deposit), when the goods available, you will need to pay the remaining amount of the price, that is 尾数.

So I think the 尾数 on your bill means the amount of money you not yet paid.

Comment: 尾数 means the number after decimal point.

Comment: Personally I haven't seen 尾数 used in that way (remaining amount), but it's possibly the right usage in certain domains or regions; In daily life, 尾数 usually mean either the fraction division of a decimal, or the last digit(s) of an integer.